# Does ffmpeg violate the SAT>IP specification (DESCRIBE syntax)?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to play a SAT>IP stream using `ffmpeg -i rtsp://sat.ip/?src=1&freq=11493&pol=h&sr=22000&msys=dvbs&pids=0,5100,5101,5101,8191`, which returns `method DESCRIBE failed: 404 Not Found`. For reference, VLC plays the stream just fine.

When `tcpflow`ing the ffmpeg traffic, I get the following:

```
192.168.002.104.34018-192.168.002.222.00554: OPTIONS rtsp://sat.ip:554/?src=1&freq=11493&pol=h&sr=22000&msys=dvbs&pids=0,5100,5101,5101,8191 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
User-Agent: Lavf58.29.100


192.168.002.222.00554-192.168.002.104.34018: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Public: OPTIONS, SETUP, PLAY, TEARDOWN, DESCRIBE


192.168.002.104.34018-192.168.002.222.00554: DESCRIBE rtsp://sat.ip:554/?src=1&freq=11493&pol=h&sr=22000&msys=dvbs&pids=0,5100,5101,5101,8191 RTSP/1.0
Accept: application/sdp
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: Lavf58.29.100


192.168.002.222.00554-192.168.002.104.34018: RTSP/1.0 404 Not Found
CSeq: 2
```

ffmpeg first issues an OPTION command, then a DESCRIBE, asking for the specified stream. The SAT>IP spec (http://www.satip.info/sites/satip/files/resource/satip_specification_version_1_2_2.pdf) however says in chap. 3.5.7:

> If  no  session  has  been  previously  setup  on  the  SAT>IP  server (and  thus  no  stream  has  been  created),  the  response to the DESCRIBE request will be error message 404 (stream not found). 
>   So in my opinion ffmpeg violates the spec when issuing a URI-specfic DESCRIBE without a SETUP, and thus the 404 response is correct.

Am I missing something here?

(By the way, of course I tried to open an issue in the ffmpeg bug tracker, but registration does not work).

Comment: So if ffmpeg sent a SETUP before the DESCRIBE it would work?

Comment: I have some patches for ffmpeg here which should fix this issue: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/compare/master...tmm1:satip-improvements

Comment: Based on (my understanding of) the SAT>IP spec, that should work, yes. Thanks a lot for your patch!

Comment: I was able to get access to a SAT>IP box and test my patch a bit, and make some improvements. Would be great if you can try it out with your equipment as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized myself that SAT>IP somewhat conflicts with the underlying RTSP spec in this respect. RTSP allows the client to issue a DESCRIBE using the desired URI, whereas SAT>IP requires the client to SETUP this URI first.

It seems that ffmpeg simply does not (cannot?) know about SAT>IP.